# Ember.js - Using {{#if}} around {{bindAttr}} with shared condition?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm on Ember-1.0.0-pre2 and I seem to be having trouble using an {{#if}} statement around an element which has a {{bindAttr class="..."}} and the binding conditions are the same. I.E. the if statment and class binding are to the same controller attribute. See code:

```
<button {{action "toggleShow" target="controller"}}>Toggle Visibility</button>
{{#if show}}
   <div {{bindAttr class="show:red:green"}}>test</div>
{{/if}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y49ch/10/

If you click the "Toggle Visibility" button several times you'll notice you get a the common error that says: "Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM. Because this is avoidable and the cause of significant performance issues in applications, this behavior is deprecated ..."

At first look that seems stupid, but that's a very primitive example of my problem. In my case, there is a computed property on the end of both bindings (if and class attribute). In both cases the computed properties share a common dependent key. When that common dependent key changes it causes both helpers to be update and thus the error.

Is this a bug? I can guess what's happening here, but it seems like I should be able to do this safely.

---

*EDIT: The above is a* **primitive example** *of the problem I'm having. It's meant to show it in a very simple way. Below is a more complex example.*

Template:

```
<button {{action "toggleValue" target="controller"}}>Toggle Value</button><br>
{{#if greaterThanTen}}
  <div {{bindAttr class="isOdd:red:green"}}>test</div>
{{/if}}
```

Javascript:

```
App.myController = Ember.Controller.create({
  value: 10,

  greaterThanTen: function() {
    return this.get('value') > 10;
  }.property('value'),

  isOdd: function() {
    return this.get('value') % 2 === 1;
  }.property('value'),

  toggleValue: function() {
    this.set('value', (this.get('isOdd') ? 10 : 11));
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y49ch/16/

Comment: I'm sorry, but why do you need to use `bindAttr` in this case? If that div will *only* be visible when `show` is true, you can simply say `<div class="red">test</div>` without another call to the computed property (or show in this code). I don't know what your real code looks like but if the 2nd call to that computed property happens only when the element is visible, as shown in the sample above, it doesn't seem to be needed, so maybe changing that would help. But the problem may be elsewhere; as far as I remember computed properties are cached (are they really? anyone?)

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe, I've update the question to reflex a more real world example of my problem. Sorry if my original question was confusing, it was intended to demonstrated the problem it the most basic form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it now. Your original code had both points watching the same property which got me a little confused, but now it makes more sense. I can't really get what's going on, but I suspect it might have something to do with the runloop.

I've changed your code a little (see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/y49ch/22/)) so that div is now a child view. Some of your properties were moved from the controller to the view (does your spec allow these guys to be at the view or does it *have* to be at the controller? unless I missed something only the view should be concerned about `isOdd` and `toggleValue` at this point) and the css is bound through `classNameBindings` watching for the `value` property that is bound to the parent view.

```
App.myController = Ember.Controller.create({
  value: 10,

  greaterThanTen: function() {
    return this.get('value') > 10;
  }.property('value') 

});

App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'my-view',
    valueBinding: 'controller.value', 
    toggleValue: function() {
        this.set('value', (this.get('isOdd') ? 10 : 11));
    },
    isOdd: function() {
         return this.get('value') % 2 === 1;
    }.property('value'),
    ChildView: Em.View.extend({
        classNameBindings: 'parentView.isOdd:red:green'        
    })
});
```

Now, the template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="my-view">
  <button {{action "toggleValue"}}>Toggle Value</button><br>
  {{#if greaterThanTen}}
    {{#view view.ChildView}}
       test
    {{/view}}
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

Since the default tag for the View is div, it renders the same html, and it totally acts as a different view and prevents unecessary re-render.

**Edit**: Just as proof of concept, I've added a button to add to the value instead of just toggle so you can actually see the color changing after it gets visible. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/y49ch/23/)

Let me know if this is good for you

Comment: Thanks a lot for you're answer and taking the time to formulate it well. We actually settled on using an additional class in the {{bindAttr}} to hide the element (rather than the {{if}}), but using a ChildView would likely have worked just as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @WesleyWorkman just out of curiosity, can you show what you're passing as argument on `bindAttr`?